# pyenv proxy not work on MAC

Tags: python, pyenv

As described in the title, the following config, doesn't enable the proxy.

```
export http_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
export http_proxys="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"

pyenv install 3.5.2
```

is there other methods?

Comment: Change `http_proxys` to `https_proxy`, as discussed below. Both doing a pre-rex `export https_proxy=...`  and an explicit `https_proxy=... pyenv install ...` will work exactly the same. But the environment variable name must be correct of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no inline version of the answer from @Leon:

```
export https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
# do something
unset https_proxy
```

Comment: I noticed that you have a typo in your question. It should be `https_proxy` instead of `http_proxys`. I guess pyenv is working through HTTPS protocol so none of your 'export' gonna work in that case.

Comment: woo, that's it. Tnx

Answer (score 7):

### Add proxy for pyenv not work

here:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:58591; export HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:58591; export ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:51837

pyenv install -v 3.10.6
```

and

```
https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:51837 pyenv install -v 3.10.6
```

not work

## Workaround: manually download and move to pyenv cache

except use proxy, if you just want to speed up pyenv, another way is:

manually download **python zip file**, put into **pyenv cache**

steps:

1. download https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz

   - which show when `pyenv install 3.7.3`
   - eg

     - wget: `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz`
     - wget use https proxy: `wget -e "https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:58591" https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz`
2. move downloaded `Python-3.7.3.tar.xz` into `~/.pyenv/cache`

   - create folder `mkdir ~/.pyenv/cache` if not existed

Answer (score 6):

After try lots of methods, it can only work in this way:

```
https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 pyenv install -v 3.5.2
```